# Add right click option to chrome extension's on web page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension. I would like to know if it is possible to add a right-click option to a Chrome extension's icon.

When I click right on-page in right-click menulist it should show chrome extension icon and its name.

How do I do that using Chrome Web Developer?

Comment: [Chrome extension: add option to right click menu when clicking certain HTML element](//stackoverflow.com/a/11463132)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for Contextmenus.

Update extension's menifest.json with

```
                  "background": {  
                      "scripts": ["menus.js"],  //menu.js will include the code to crate the context  
                      "persistent": false  
                   },  
                   "permissions": ["contextMenus"],  
                   "icons":{  
                           "128": "contexticon.png"
                   }
```

Write code in menu.js

```
             var contextMenuItem = {
                    "id": "iconid",
                    "title": "iconTitle",
                    "contexts": ["all"]  // type of context
             };
             chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);
```

Note: The options for context menus are: "all", "page", "frame", "selection", "link", "editable", "image", "video", "audio", "launcher", "browser_action", or "page_action"

Comment: I want to show chrome extension name on right-click event.  For this event which context menus should select?   For "selection" context menus it working. I want to add for right clicks event on the browser

Comment: @Pradeep, you can take a look here:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/contextMenus/basic/sample.js

Comment: As I have checked, you can use "all" instead of " selection".

Comment: After adding "all" in contextMenus it's working.  Thank you for helping @Vishal

Comment: @Pradeep,  Well, you can up-vote the answer, I have edited it... Thanks.

Comment: chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {

    if ({"context": ["selection"]}) {
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
            "id": "sampleContextMenu",
            "title": "Selected Text",
            "contexts": ["selection"],
            "onclick": selected_data
        });
    }
    else {
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
            "id": "sampleContex",
            "title": "homepage",
            "contexts": ["all"],
            "onclick": homepage_data
        });
    }
});

Comment: I am trying to use if else condition but its working for "selection" but not working for "all"

Comment: var contextMenuItem = {
 "id": "spend",
 "title": "spend",
 "contexts": ["all"]
};
chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);

Comment: I have just used this, and it's working, kindly check the if else conditions:

Comment: first we have to check if any text selected then show "selection" context menus if not then only show "all" context menus, not selection context menus    How we can achieve this in background.js